# Google oauth, Facebook

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, facebook-oauth

When A person has a Gmail /Facebook account sign with EXAMPLE@GMAIL.COM. Then user data is stored in MongoDB. But how can we show the user who is logged in to my application/ website?
in my case, I am able to get the user who logged in and storing the data in mongodb. But I'm not able to show the user who is logged in.

[image: When I tried to log in with Facebook I get the URL as like this]

How can I show the login user in the place of the login?

Comment: so, when you do the auth handshaking, you will should receive the email address/name in the JWT returned...SO LONG AS you requested it within the `scope` of the payload. you should use the values from that for user info....if you have more custom info like "nickname", then you would want to fetch that and store it in a cookie or localStorage

Comment: When I tried to save in local storage from my node js code, I'm not able to store that.

Comment: I dont see your code, but there is no "local storage" in node...this is a frontend browser/JS thing